# How to compute a percentage in pivot table in Excel based on the combination of column & line

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to compute the percentage of `Action` that are `Done` by `Category` on line axis combined with `Level` on column axis in a Pivot Table

| Action | Category | Level | Done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Category 1 | Level 1 |  |
| 2 | Category 1 | Level 2 | x |
| 3 | Category 1 | Level 3 |  |
| 4 | Category 1 | Level 3 |  |
| 5 | Category 2 | Level 3 |  |
| 6 | Category 2 | Level 3 | x |
| 7 | Category 3 | Level 1 |  |
| 8 | Category 3 | Level 1 |  |
| 9 | Category 3 | Level 1 |  |
| 10 | Category 3 | Level 1 |  |
| 11 | Category 3 | Level 1 | x |
| 12 | Category 3 | Level 2 |  |
| 13 | Category 3 | Level 3 |  |
| 14 | Category 3 | Level 3 |  |

Resulting in the following Pivot Table :

| Line | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 |  | 100% |  |
| Category 2 |  |  | 50% |
| Category 3 | 20% |  |  |

In the Pivot Table of Excel, the only computation option available for the `Done` field is to compute the `Percentage of the Line` or the `Percentage of the Column`. There is no combination of both Line & Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is placed in the range A1:D15 (and there are no other data below it), place in cell E2 this formula:

```
=(IF(COUNTIFS(B$1:B2,B2,C$1:C2,C2,D$1:D2,"x")=1,COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2,D:D,"x")/COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2),0))
```

Drag the formula down accordingly. Choose the header you like (say "percentage") and write it in cell E1. Create a pivot table similar to the one you have putting level in the columns, category in the rows and percentage in the values. Set values as "sum" and its format as percentage (you can do so by selecting the values area, right-clicking and choosing cells format).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So I guess there is no way to do it directly in the Pivot Table without adding a column prior

Comment: Not as far as i know. And the extra column it's just a good enouth solution to make any further investigation kind of futile in my extimations.